# How to invoke the mouseenter event programmatically via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my html structure I have one anchor tag element which has hoverIntent plugin event attached.

```
     $('a').hoverIntent(function(event){// some code to show popup;})
```

Whenever I hover on the anchor tag manually it does some ajax call and brings back the data from service and shows popup.

I want to trigger the mouseenter/hover/mousemove (anything which can bring the popup) from code (without any manual action)

I tried basic jquery functions like

```
   $('selector').trigger('hover') and
   $('selector').trigger('mouseenter')
```

But nothing worked, Is this possible to invoke the hover/mouseenter functionality without users interruption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hoverIntent` jQuery plugin uses both `mouseenter` and `mousemove` events to determine whether to fire or not. If you simply trigger the `mouseenter` event nothing will happen because of this.

You'll need to first call the `mouseenter` event and include a mouse position. Then you need to call the `mousemove` event, also including the mouse position.

This [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/amugod/2) shows the example. If you hover the "Hover me" item without first hovering the green box, nothing happens. Is you hover the green box to make it red, the "hover me" link will work afterwards. To trigger this programmatically without first hovering the green box, use these calls:

```
var e = $.Event('mouseenter');
e.pageX = 50;
e.pageY = 50;
$("#testing").trigger(e);

var e2 = $.Event('mousemove');
e2.pageX = 50;
e2.pageY = 50;
$("#testing").trigger(e2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always re-factor your code.  Instead of:

```
$('a').hoverIntent(function(event){// some code to show popup;})
```

do:

```
function myFunc(event){// some code to show popup;}

$('a').hoverIntent(myFunc);
```

Then, you can just call myFunc directly instead of trying to "mimic" a DOM event.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the source of that plugin, it should in fact be firing when 'mouseenter' is triggered. Have you tried triggering it using the following code?

```
$('selector').mouseenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous function, you could just make a reusable one. It looks like the easiest way to go.

```
function doThat(event){
    // do some stuff
}

$('a').hoverIntent(doThat);
```

And whenever you need to trigger the function, you just execute `doThat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not just call your ajax method from a function? Why do you need to use the hoverIntent if you want it call it from your own code or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know think you can actually trigger a `mouseenter`.  It might be more beneficial to

```
$('selector').bind('focus', function(e) {
 //code
});

//Then do
$('selector').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do a jQuery hover function is as follows

```
$('selector').hover(
    function(){ //This function is called on mouseenter();
        //code
    },function(){ //This function is called on mouseleave();
        //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery hooks, you can always get the browser to really, fully simulate the event:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent( 'mouseenter', false, false, window,
                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                    false, false, false, false, 0, null );
$('selector')[0].dispatchEvent(evt);

// or, for multiple matched
$('selector').each(function(){ this.dispatchEvent(evt); });
```

*For more details, read [the documentation on `initMouseEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent).*

Comment: I tried above option, but it gave error for dispatchEvent as undefined method. Any other way to do this?

Comment: @Raj What OS/browser/version, and what type of object was the result of `[0]` or `this` that you were calling `dispatchEvent` on?

Comment: Windows 7 - 64 bit, Browser - Google chrome..My selector i.e. $('#divid a.class') returns me the desired anchor tag. and I used below code..$('#divid a.class').dispatchEvent(evt) where evt is defined as you mentioned above.

Comment: @Raj As shown in my answer above, you need to use `[0].dispatchEvent(…)` to fetch the DOM element out of the jQuery wrapper object.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is only working for click event, not for mouseenter.
When used mouseenter as event, it returns true.
But for click event it is properly calling click event.
Code:
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

evt.initMouseEvent( 'mouseenter', true, true, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    false, false, false, false, 0, null );

Comment: @Raj I have not tested to guarantee that it works, but your persistent inability to either directly copy code samples or critically think about what the values need to be surprises me.

Comment: The code is as below:
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
evt.initMouseEvent( 'mouseenter', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null );
$('div# a')[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
I changed some of the parameter values as the values mentioned in your sample didn't work.